# How to check if string is text or scientific number?

Tags: vba, excel, scientific-notation, isnumeric

I am curious, if there is option in VBA to check if string is just text or its number in scientific format e.g.(0,212E+01).

I tried `isNumeric, val` and some other functions,but without success. Also I found solution which is testing middle character and if its number, but it seems a bit shabby to me.

So my question is, if there is some more reliable solution to determine this?

Edit:

So steveo40 is correct, my mistake was in decimal separator....

Comment: IsNumeric returns true for "212E+01"

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Dim x As Range
Set x = Range("A1") 'Ur cell for which your are loking to find the format

If (x.NumberFormat = "0.00E+00") Then
MsgBox "Sceientific"
End If
```